# Constellation of charges in a quadrupole

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, multipole-expansion

I’d like to know if any constelation of 4 charges is a quadrupole. I have a task where there are 2 positive and 2 negative charged particles in the corners of a rectangle. And this is a quadrupole. Is it still one if I place them differently or if I have 3 positive and 1 negative?
About the second question: I’d guess that it’s not a quadrupole anymore but a more complicated dipole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at some point in space their fields will sum to zero, for four charges this can happen in two locations. For example, if you have the charges evenly spaced in a plane ordered as (+,-,+,-) then you will have two quadrupoles midway between the charges at heights above the plane $\pm z_0$. If you have them ordered as (+,+,-,-) then the quadrupoles will be in the plane between the (+,+) section and (-,-) section.

It gets hard to imagine the field in your other scenario, I can imagine one scenario where the positive charges are on one side and the negative on the other. This configuration will give you two quadrupoles and a dipole. I'm not sure if this is the case generally.

Comment: i dont exaclty know what you mean by  this notation: (+,-,+,-)  or (+,+). could you explain that ?

Comment: + is a positive charge, - is a negative charge. The order in the brackets corresponds to the position in the plane.

Comment: okay. and you said they are evenly spaced. does that mean that they all have the same distance from each other ? so that they are placed on a cirlce

Comment: @petermafai the charges can be placed along a line, a circle is not necessary. They also don't have to be evenly spaced, it's just the easiest scenario if you want to calculate that particular configuration.

Comment: @petermafai I can try and elaborate further if it still isn't clear?